# How to apply dense rank in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am new to Mongo Db and would appreciate some help with this query.my transection ids and create date are same like

```
      TRANSACTION_ID             CREATE_DATE   
 "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
 "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"    "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
 "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
 "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"   "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018"
 "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"    "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018"
```

but how to add DENSE_RANK like

```
 DENSE_RANK         TRANSACTION_ID             CREATE_DATE   
     1          "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
     1          "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
     1          "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
     2          "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"   "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018"
     2          "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"   "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018"
```

any one please help me

Answer (score -1):

You can use an update query;

```
db.test.update({"TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"},{"$set" : {"DENSE_RANK" : 1}},{multi : true})
```

and

```
db.test.update({"TRANSACTION_ID" : "ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"},{"$set" : {"DENSE_RANK" : 2}},{multi : true})
```

The output is :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd188c34caa61c57872dbe7"),
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142",
    "CREATE_DATE" : "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018",
    "DENSE_RANK" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd188c34caa61c57872dbe8"),
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142",
    "CREATE_DATE" : "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018",
    "DENSE_RANK" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd188c34caa61c57872dbe9"),
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142",
    "CREATE_DATE" : "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018",
    "DENSE_RANK" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd189044caa61c57872dbec"),
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "ffff0a0a0983UY:-111",
    "CREATE_DATE" : "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018",
    "DENSE_RANK" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd189044caa61c57872dbed"),
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "ffff0a0a0983UY:-111",
    "CREATE_DATE" : "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018",
    "DENSE_RANK" : 2.0
}
```

Comment: this query use only  one (or) two (or) three transections ids how to use  diffrent diffrent multiple records avilable  transections id and automatic added multiple transections ids how to add dense_rank please suggest me @Senthur Deva

Comment: Hello Senthur Deva if any possible other solutions..@ Senthur Deva